# Python Django-Helpdesk Error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: python, django, django-models

I keep getting the error mentioned in the title as I perform any of the following actions:

- Submit ticket
- Update ticket
- Take ticket

This is my first time using Django, I have no experience when it comes to building websites. Could you please help me solve this issue?

Thank you!

**Additional details:**

```
error at /helpdesk/tickets/submit/

[Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/helpdesk/tickets/submit/

Django Version: 1.8.3
Python Version: 2.7.10
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'markdown_deux',
 'bootstrapform',
 'helpdesk',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\helpdesk\views\staff.py" in create_ticket
  862.             ticket = form.save(user=request.user)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\helpdesk\forms.py" in save
  287.                 files=files,
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\helpdesk\lib.py" in send_templated_mail
  147.     return msg.send(fail_silently)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py" in send
  303.         return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py" in send_messages
  100.             new_conn_created = self.open()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py" in open
  58.             self.connection = connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)
File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py" in __init__
  256.             (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py" in connect
  316.         self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py" in _get_socket
  291.         return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py" in create_connection
  575.         raise err

Exception Type: error at /helpdesk/tickets/submit/
Exception Value: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll do you a favour. This code looks like its having problems whenever it tries to send an email (based on `smtplib.py` showing up). Which would happen at any of those actions.

Check your email server.

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py" in _get_socket
  291.         return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py" in create_connection
  575.         raise err
```